# Makefile assignment to special variable .DEFAULT_GOAL is not expanded

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL=${IMG}

BUILD_DIR=build

IMG=${BUILD_DIR}/hd60M.img
BIN=${addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,${addsuffix .bin,${objects}}}

${IMG}:${BIN}
    touch $@
```

`make -n` gives the result:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `${IMG}'.  Stop.
```

If I change the first line to `.DEFAULT_GOAL=build/hd60M.img`, it works without error messages.
It seems that assignment to `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is not expanded. Why?

Comment: It looks like in GNU make 3.81 for some reason the value of `.DEFAULT_GOAL` wasn't being properly expanded as it should have been.  This was fixed in newer versions of GNU make as you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:=` instead of `=`, `()` instead of `{}`, and expand variables AFTER setting them:

```
# Expand rhs on assignment
IMG := $(BUILD_DIR)/hd60M.img

…

# Set default goal after variable is set
.DEFAULT_GOAL := $(IMG)
```

Comment: There's no reason to prefer `$(...)` over `${...}`; they both are identical as far as make is concerned.

Comment: @MadScientist You are absolutely right, it is style only.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem is due to my make version.

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

After I updated GNU make to the newest version, the problem is solved.